# Watch face App packaged by android studio can not sync to android wear?

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, moto-360

I use android studio to create a wear app and didn't change anything(Only a watch face).Then I package it and get a signature apk. I install it on my phone(Nexus 4),but it can not auto install on Moto 360.

I tried to install some wear app in Google Play,but they can auto install on it.

I don't know why.Should I change anything on original code?

Comment: Was it signed with a release key or a debug key?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution,that's very simple:
add

```
<uses-permission
android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

on **phone Manifest**.